# the number of elements in $\operatorname{Aff}(2, \mathbb{Z}_2)$

Tags: group-theory

I have a question. Find the number elements in $\operatorname{Aff}(2, \mathbb{Z}_2)$

My intuition tells me $\left|\operatorname{Aff}(2, \mathbb{Z}_2)\right| = 24$ because it contains every bijective function from $\mathbb{F}^2_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^2_2$ and since $\mathbb{F}^2_2$ has 4 elements therefore $\operatorname{Aff}(2, \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong S_4$, but I am not sure how to formally prove it except listing everything out and check if it is right. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is your definition of $\text{Aff}(2, \mathbb{F}_2)$ the set of all bijections from $\mathbb{F}_2^2$ to itself?

Comment: @MichaelBarz No, the definition is what Anurag A described

Comment: This group is often denoted by ${\rm AGL}(2,2)$. More generally, ${\rm AGL}(d,q) = V \rtimes {\rm GL}(d,q)$, with $V = {\mathbb F}_q^d$, which has order $q^d(q^d-1)(q^d-q) \cdots (q^d-q^{d-1})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $\operatorname{Aff}(2,\Bbb{Z}_2)$ we are looking for affine maps that are given by $\mathbf{x} \mapsto A\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{b}$, where $\mathbf{x, b} \in \Bbb{F}_2^2$ and $A \in GL(2,\Bbb{F}_2)$. Number of such $\mathbf{b}'s$ is clearly $4$. So we should find the number of invertible matrices $A$.

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$, with $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb{F}_2$. For invertibility of $A$, we want the columns to be linearly independent. So the first column has to be a non-zero column. This means we can choose any of $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ for the first column (so $3$ choices out of $4$ total possibilities). For the second column, we should NOT have a multiple of the first column so out of $4$ we can only have $2$ good choices (that are not multiples). In all $6$ possible invertible matrices.

Thus the number of pairs $(A,\mathbf{b})$ is $24$.

---

Based on **@verret's** suggestion I am adding these remarks:

Let $F(\mathbf{x})=A\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{b}$ and $G(\mathbf{x})=C\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{d}$. When can these maps be identically equal? For them to be same we should have $F(\mathbf{0})=G(\mathbf{0})$. This means $\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{d}$. Now we have

$$F(\mathbf{x})-G(\mathbf{x})=(A-C)\mathbf{x}.$$
But if $F$ and $G$ are the same maps, then this means $\forall \, \mathbf{x}$ we will have $F(\mathbf{x})-G(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{0}$. Consequently we will have  $A=C$. Thus distinct coefficients will give distinct maps.

Comment: Thank you very much! This makes a lot of sense.

Comment: To be more complete, I think one should add a proof that different coefficients give different maps. (This is not that hard, but is important.)

Comment: @verret I took your suggestion and have added the required proof :-)